# how to exit developer mode on android 4.0 ice cream sandwich

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, developer-options

I have a Sony-Ericsson Xperia Arc S with android 4.0,
the dev mode was activated by mistake by a non tech person.
( so now every touch/drag draws a line, and on the top it shows x,y coordinates )

I can't find how to disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want that line / coordinate overlay gone, disable `Settings - Developer Options - Pointer location`.

Answer (score 1):

To Disable Developer mode goto settings-> **developer{ }** then there is a slider on  top of Developer options which you can on/off.

Comment: for me it's only Settings -> Developer Options and inside there's no slider only grouped checkboxes,   "user interface" ( Strict mode enabled, pointer location, show touches ... ) ... "Apps" ( Don't keep activities, Background all ANRs, Show all ANRs)

Comment: @Omu I do wonder why it is so, I remembered that Android 4.0/4.1 devices do have a global toggle controlling Dev Options on the top bar, and Sony did very few UI changes so they shouldn't have touched it.